# sqlite version error with ogr2ogr

Tags: sql, spatialite, ogr2ogr, mac, sqlite

I am trying to randomly select some points from a shape file using ogr2ogr and an SQL query via sqlite but it seems to baulk at the sqlite version:

```
ogr2ogr -sql "SELECT * FROM probe_2004to2012 WHERE D2004 > 0 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 10" -dialect sqlite ./Probing/probe_2004_r10.shp ./Probing/probe_2004to2012.shp

ERROR 6: The SQLite version is to old to support the SQLite SQL dialect
```

Given that I tried updating sqlite3 in my /usr/bin/ from the jan 2013 version and it is now the latest (Oct 2013) version and ogr2ogr still throws up this error I suspect it may be something else that's wrong.
I know I can select random points in QGIS using the "Research Tools" toolbox but I would really like to be able to script this as I have a lot of random selecting to do.

-update:
its seems ogr2ogr supports

```
-dialect sqlite3
```

as a valid flag and that seems to get a simplified sql query to parse but the random() selection won't get through.

After the discussion below it seems that ogr2ogr is not parsing the -dialect flag "properly". The sqlite3 flag is ignored and ogr defaults to its built in sql, which is why the simple queries work. Why the sqlite flag is coming up ERROR 6 I don't know. Yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My nose was right! It was a multiple path issue in OSX. I had multiple installs of ogr and gdal conflicting despite them not being on my path as defined by .bash_profile but this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8841666/2062470 sorted me out.

Comment: Can you mark this as the answer?

Answer (score 2):

> Since **GDAL/OGR 1.10**, the SQLite "dialect" can be used as an alternate
>   SQL dialect to the OGR SQL dialect. This assumes that GDAL/OGR is
>   **built with support for SQLite (>= 3.6)**, and preferably with **Spatialite
>   support** too to benefit from spatial functions.

Source: http://www.gdal.org/ogr/ogr_sql_sqlite.html

So you need to build GDAL (>= 1.10) against SQLite (>= 3.6) and SpatiaLite (>= 3.0) in order to use the `-dialect SQLite` option.

In order to understand which versions of SQLite and (eventually) SpatiaLite you are using, simply execute:

```
ogrinfo foo.shp -dialect sqlite -sql "select sqlite_version()"
ogrinfo foo.shp -dialect sqlite -sql "select spatialite_version()"
```

Comment: It seems that my sqlite command isn't aliased to sqlite3 and that is the source of the issue with not finding a valid sqlite. My installation of GDAL is the KyngChaos build and should have everything set correctly otherwise (no guarantees of course).

Comment: If you execute the two queries above and post the versions, maybe we can understand where is the issue. However, the error message is well self-explanatory, so you need to update or build GDAL yourself.

Comment: Running the commands "as is" I get the same error, if I adjust the dialect flag to sqlite3 I get    `ERROR 1: SQL Expression Parsing Error: syntax error`

Comment: And what says `gdalinfo --version` ? This is the latest GDAL complete build on KyngChaos: http://www.kyngchaos.com/files/software/frameworks/GDAL_Complete-1.10.dmg It should solve the issue. Hope this helps.

Comment: I get GDAL 1.10.1, released 2013/08/26

Comment: What is odd is that it is the specific query that causes an issue. ´ogr2ogr -dialect sqlite3 -sql "SELECT * FROM probe_2004to2012 WHERE D2004 > 0" ./Probing/probe_2004_r10.shp ./Probing/probe_2004to2012.shp
' works fine so it seems that it really can't be a dialect issue. Or maybe it can, I really don't know at what level this is baulking.

Comment: Well, exiting bash a couple of times more, just to make sure my profile was read in, seems to have done the trick for the dialect issue. I still get `ERROR 1: SQL Expression Parsing Error: syntax error`with my query but that is another issue.

Comment: The `ogr2ogr` expression you posted in the question is right and it works fine for me on Win7 (GDAL 1.10.1, SQLite 3.7.9, SpatiaLite 3.0.0-stable): records are selected randomly, as requested. Note: `-dialect sqlite3` is wrong, it should be only `-dialect sqlite`.

Comment: Even if I set `alias sqlite='sqlite3'` in my profile I still need the sqlite3 flag or it won't parse anything and I get the original ERROR 6. With sqlite3 I get `ERROR 1: SQL Expression Parsing Error: syntax error' on many queries but not all. I smell path issues yet again but maybe I'm just blaming the usual suspect.

Comment: You don't need that alias. That's why `-dialect sqlite3` returns `ERROR 1: SQL Expression Parsing Error: syntax error`.

Comment: Yes I do. If I don't then it returns the ERROR 6.

Comment: From terminal: `$ ogrinfo ./Probing/probe_2004to2012.shp -dialect sqlite3 -sql "select sqlite_version()"
INFO: Open of `./Probing/probe_2004to2012.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.
ERROR 1: SQL Expression Parsing Error: syntax error
$ ogrinfo ./Probing/probe_2004to2012.shp -dialect sqlite -sql "select sqlite_version()"
INFO: Open of `./Probing/probe_2004to2012.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.
ERROR 6: The SQLite version is to old to support the SQLite SQL dialect
$ which sqlite
$ which sqlite3
/Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.framework/Programs/sqlite3

`

Comment: I did ´sudo ln sqlite3 sqlite' in the framework/Programs directory and 'which sqlite' then returned this hardlink and executing it started the correct sqlite3 but still the ogr call comes back with the same error if I don't specify sqlite3.

Comment: It seems that ogr isn't recognising the dialect flag and is simply defaulting to its own SQL. Perhaps.